# Using malloc to create a string containing elements from another string in c

Tags: c, string, pointers, malloc

Create a function in C that takes a string as a parameter and copy it to a new string.
If the original string is "abc", then the new string should be "aabbcc", if the original string is "4", then the newstring should be 44 etc. I believe i understand the concepts needed to solve a problem like this, but i just can't get the new string to be printed in the console. Here is my function:

```
void eco(char * str)
{

    int count = 0; 

    /*Counts the number of symbols in the string*/
    while(*(str + count) != '\0')
    {
       count++;              
    }

    /*Memory for the new string, wich should be 6 chars long ("aabbcc").*/
    char * newstr = malloc(sizeof(char *) * (count * 2)); 

    /*Creating the content for newstr.*/
    while(count > 0)
    {
       *newstr = *str;  //newstr[0] = 'a'
       *newstr++;       //next newstr pos
       *newstr = *str;  //newstr[1] = 'a'
       *str++;          //next strpos
       count--;         
    }

    /*I can't understand why this would not print aabbcc*/
    printf("%s", newstr);

    /*free newstr from memory*/
    free(newstr);
}
```

I have tried to print every char individually inside the while loop that creates the content for newstr, and that work. But when i try with the "%s"-flag i either get strange non-keyboard symbols or nothing at all.

Comment: Please fix the code ident!

Comment: Don't forget to allocate space for, and initialise, the 0 to terminate the string.

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(char *)` is almost certainly not what you want.

Comment: Also, you're modifying the value of `newstr`, so that it's no longer pointing to the beginning of the string when you want to display it.

Comment: I have tried with adding one additional char in malloc for the '\0' and also i've tried to "rewind" newstr to the beginning by using newstr--; in a loop before the print. Same problem still though.

Answer (score 2):

> I can't understand why this would not print "aabbcc"

It wouldn't do it for two reasons:

- You are not passing a pointer to the *beginning* of the string, and
- Because you did not add a null terminator

To fix the first problem, store the pointer to the block allocated to `newstr` in a temporary before doing the increments.

To fix the second problem, add `*newstr = '\0'` after the loop, and adjust `malloc` call to add an extra `char` for the terminator.

```
// Do not multiply by sizeof(char), because the standard requires it to be 1
// You used sizeof(char*), which is wrong too.
char * newstr = malloc((count * 2) + 1);
char *res = newstr; // Store the original pointer
// Your implementation of the actual algorithm looks right
while (...) {
    ... // Do the loop
}

*newstr = '\0';
printf("%s\n", res); // Pass the original pointer
```

Comment: Two more things, he forgot a second newstr++, and there's no need to dereference *newstr++ (at the OP code sample).

Answer (score 1):

Your loop advances `newstr`, so after it completes, it's not pointing at the beginning of the string anymore.  You need to save the original pointer to use for printing.

Answer (score 0):

For a start this line

```
char * newstr = malloc(sizeof(char *) * (count * 2));
```

should be

```
char * newstr = malloc(1 + (count * 2));
```

to include the null character

Then you forgot to add it

Also `newstr` points to the end to the new string